# Converting PDF to PCL5 on Windows?

Tags: pdf, printer-control-language

In my application, I need to convert PDF docs to PCL5 generic files to send to FTP PCL capable printers. Printing to file would be a last resort, I would prefer a small-footprint command line tool or API that will do the job.

I've seen some mention of doing this on Linux using Ghostscript, but I've got no idea how to replicate this on windows.

Many thanks

Comment: Ghostscript is available for Windows as well. All commandline options are the same on all platforms. It's just that the "exe" on Linux is called `gs` while on Windows it's `gswin32c.exe`. So if you have a guide to be followed on Linux, it would be easy to replicate this on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) is available also for windows.
You can test It with opening a command window and using the gswin32c command.
You can build a shell script that send the "gswin32c" command with all the options needed.

[This](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gs) could help you find the right sequence of flag and otpions

Comment: Thanks, been there before but I could not find a windows - specific build. I'll download the latest and look inside the gzip file.

Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, I followed the wrong link - found the windows binary under the sourceforge releases.

Comment: You da man. Thank you.

Shall I push my luck and ask if you have idea where I can get a PCL5e Device driver?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example command that would generate ***one*** color PCL/XL from ***three*** PDF input files in a single go:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
    -dBATCH ^
    -dNOPAUSE ^
    -dSAFER ^
    -sDEVICE=pxlcolor ^
    -sOutputFile=c:/path/to/my.pcl ^
    first.pdf ^
    2nd.pdf ^
    no3.pdf
```

(use `-sDEVICE=pxlmono` if you want black+White PCL output only). If you know your target printer in advance, you'd probably want to use some other `-sDEVICE=...` param.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are searching for a generic printer driver:
maybe this [hpijs-pcl5e](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/hpijs-pcl5e) could fit, or also you can try [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html)

[Hp universal](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=503548&prodTypeId=18972&objectID=c00751649) could be another starting point.

[OpenPrinting](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/openprinting) in general has a lot of material you can dig. I'm sorry but my knowledge about this subject arrives just here. :)

Comment: Ok, I can't figure out how to register the ppd file as a usable device for Ghostscript.

Comment: Create and register a devnode for your device.
A way to do It is by using the rundll32 printui.dll command.

Comment: See rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /?

Comment: No, don't use **any** specific PPD file. This will only put device specific options (suitable for a certain printer model into the output file, and later, once you want to print on your actutal device using FTP, your target printer may get confused and refuse the job. Rather call Ghostscript directly (without any PPD) and you'll get a generic PCL output. (I'll add an example command in an extra answer -- these comments are not suitable for this).